# getActionProvider is undefined for the type MenuItemCompat?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a sharing provider to my action bar following the guide here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ShareActionProvider

However when trying to add the below as instructed inside my onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
// Set up ShareActionProvider's default share intent
MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)
        MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());
```

There's an error saying that getActionProvider is undefined for the type MenuItemCompat, though it is documented:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#getActionProvider(android.view.MenuItem)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing your XML, define your actionProviderClass in your menu layout:

```
<item android:id=...
...
yourapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

and obtain a reference to the ShareActionProvider with

```
ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
```

Keep in mind, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ShareActionProvider) uses examples from the support library. If this is the case then, in your menu layout:

```
<item android:id=...
...
yourapp:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

and to obtain a reference to the ShareActionProvider:

```
ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
```

Comment: Yup did that in the xml, but the problem is with the MenuItemCompat not having the say function.

Comment: I've deleted my own answer since you've updated yours with the full solution. Cheers!